# CSS and html flip box try to make

Tags: html, css

Hi i am trying to make css flip box but when it flip not show next box..the front box message is "Hover to flip!" and when i hove the mouse on it it flip and show the message "!pilf ot revoH"

```
   --CSS styling--
<style>
.flipper {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    margin:10px auto;
}
.flipper {
    perspective: 1000;
}
.flipper .flip {
    -webkit-transition: .75s;
    -webkit-transform-style: presever-3d;
    position:relative;
}
.flipper .flip:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flipper, .flipper .front, .flipper .back {
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
}
.front {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background:#666;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.flipper .front {
    z-index:1;
}
.flipper .back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

</style>


---HTML code---

<div class="fliper">
    <div class="flip">
        <div class="front">Hover to flip!</div>

        <div class="backe">Hello!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyone can suggest me where is my mistake?

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/r9nRR/

Comment: -webkit-transform-style: presever-3d   is not legel, it should be preserve

Answer (score 0):

try adding transform-style:

```
.fliper {
      -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

i cant see your markup but you can check out this tut also:

http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip